# How to link it to another div/page?

Tags: html

I want to make this image disappear. It did happen, but now I need to link it to another div/page? What html do I need to accomplish this?

```
<div data-role="page" style="width: 100%;">
<img src="pic/front cover.jpg" onclick="this.style.display='none'" style="width:100%;">
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you don't use <a> ?

Comment: You need to provide more details about your goal. What do you mean from "I need to link it to another div/page?"

Comment: You must to read before ask. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: im sorry for unreasonable question. what i want todo is splash screen. i just know the term. im very new in this field. sorry again.

Answer (score 1):

You wrap your image in an anchor tag, like so:

```
<a data-role="page" href="/other-page">
    <img src="pic/front cover.jpg" onclick="this.style.display='none'" style="width:100%;">
</a>
```

In case you want to have the anchor tag behave as a div, you need to add some CSS properties to it. The first thing that comes to mind is `display: block`.

Comment: im sorry for unreasonable question. what i want todo is splash screen. i just know the term. im very new in this field. sorry again. btw thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not the greatest way of asking a question - but is this what you are looking for?

```
<div data-role="page" style="width: 100%;">
<a href="#mypageplace">
    <img src="pic/front cover.jpg" onclick="this.style.display='none'" style="width:100%;"></a>
</div>

<div id="mypageplace"></div>
```

here is a codepen -http://codepen.io/mslfire/pen/MawVLB

Comment: im sorry for unreasonable question. what i want todo is splash screen. i just know the term. im very new in this field. sorry again. btw thanks for the answer.